# Play WAV file using Excel VBA in mac os

Tags: excel, vba, wav

I am trying to play wav file in mac using the below code.

`Option Explicit
Private Declare PtrSafe Function sndPlaySound32 Lib "winmm.dll" _
Alias "sndPlaySoundA" (ByVal lpszSoundName As String, ByVal uFlags As Long) As Long

Sub PlaySound()
Call sndPlaySound32("C:\XXXXXXXXX.wav", &H8) 'you can change to any .wav file here
End Sub`

But I m getting the below error, please can someone guide how to play wav file in mac using vba.

[Error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wZvKy.png)

Expecting a wav file to be played at end of my VBA execution.